# How to change a user control from type "Windows Forms" to type "WPF"

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, datagridview

I have a user control that uses the standard windows forms classes, especially DataGridView. Now I want to switch my user control over to a control that uses WPF instead of Windows Forms.

I know how to write the control itself and the code behind. But this code assumes that I use the binding properties given by WPF.

So, when I replace Windows Forms with WPF, I would have to write a wrapper class around my data class, that is a simple List class. because neither the list nor the object class are aware of notifications and data bindings.

What would be the best approach to reuse the given data classes and the interface from the user control to the parent form class without too much dealing with data bindings.

The user control itself must only display the data, no user editing will be allowed. But it should be possible to change the data from within code.

I know that I can set WPF element values using their given name in XML, but is this still valid with a hierarchical (data grid like) element structure? And how do I this if it is possible?

Comment: the simple answer is that you can't the controls are based on total different technology, how ever your data classes should be totally unaffected, and if you have followed a Layered design pattern then your data classes shouldn't have any direct linkage to the GUI and should already have a interface managing their Gui interaction

Comment: WPF is working with property notification, this is not implemented in my Windows Forms class. So I need a wrapper around my 'basic' data classes to meet this MVVM architecture. The WPF user controls code behind must have methods to deal with these notifications and my 'stupid' data classes ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best approach to this problem is really implementing an additional layer of code that implements the MVVM pattern.